# How to make a filter for graph in html using json by python list data?

Tags: python, html, json, flask

list = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'April']

Required Output:
Dropdown filter of above list on HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Using jinja:

```
<select name="months">
   {% for month in list %}
   <option value="{{ month }}">{{ month }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```